# SMIME_read_PKCS7 method in OpenSSL library has input length 1200 restriction?

Tags: c++, cryptography, openssl

I'm trying to use high level API provided by OpenSSL for cryptography work.

Here it works pretty well, usually.

```
/**
 * Instructions for generating private key file and self signed certificate file.
 *
 * openssl genrsa -des3 -out keys.pem 2048
 * openssl rsa -in keys.pem -out rsa.pem
 * openssl req -new -x509 -key rsa.pem -out rsa-cert.pem -days 9999
 * 
 * Compile
 * g++ -ggdb -o exe.bex src.cpp -lcrypto
 */

//c standard library
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//openssl library
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/pkcs7.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>

//c++ standard library
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    FILE* fd = fopen("rsa.pem", "r");
    X509* x509;
    STACK_OF(X509)* x509_stack = sk_X509_new_null();
    EVP_PKEY* key;
    if (NULL != fd)
    {
        key = PEM_read_PrivateKey(fd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }
    fd = fopen("rsa-cert.pem", "r");
    if (NULL != fd)
    {
        while (NULL != (x509 = PEM_read_X509(fd, NULL, NULL, NULL)))
        {
            sk_X509_push(x509_stack, x509);
        }
        fclose(fd);
    }
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    while (!std::cin.eof()) {
        std::string msg;

        //get input text
        printf("Message to PKCS7 encrypt: ");
        fflush(stdout);
        std::getline(std::cin, msg);
        if (223 < msg.length())
        {
            // SMIME_read_PKCS7 bug, need to be fixed.
            //
            // bt:
            //#0  asn1_d2i_read_bio (in=0x60bc40, pb=0x7fffffffe238) at a_d2i_fp.c:286
            //#1  0x00007ffff7aeb762 in ASN1_item_d2i_bio (it=0x7ffff7dc2da0, in=0x60bc40, x=0x0) at a_d2i_fp.c:113
            //#2  0x00007ffff7b0201c in b64_read_asn1 (bio=0x60bc40, it=0x7ffff7dc2da0) at asn_mime.c:191
            //#3  0x00007ffff7b02dd0 in SMIME_read_ASN1 (bio=0x60af00, bcont=0x7fffffffe350, it=0x7ffff7dc2da0) at asn_mime.c:527
            //#4  0x00007ffff7b39db2 in SMIME_read_PKCS7 (bio=0x60af00, bcont=0x7fffffffe350) at pk7_mime.c:96
            //#5  0x0000000000401668 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe4b8) at ./crypto-pkcs.cpp:99
            //
            std::cout << "string too long " << msg.length() << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
        if (msg.empty())
        {
            std::cout << "string too short" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }


        //save input
        BIO* bio_input_plain_text = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
        BIO_write(bio_input_plain_text, msg.c_str(), msg.length());
        BIO_flush(bio_input_plain_text);

        //create PKCS7 object in the way of PKCS7_encrypt.
        PKCS7* pkcs7_encrypt = PKCS7_encrypt(x509_stack, bio_input_plain_text, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), 0);
        if (NULL == pkcs7_encrypt) {
            std::cout << "PKCS7_encrypt returns NULL" <<  std::endl; return -1;}

        //dump encryped info.
        BIO* bio_encrypted_smime = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
        if (SMIME_write_PKCS7(bio_encrypted_smime, pkcs7_encrypt, bio_input_plain_text, 0) != 1){ std::cout << "SMIME_write_PKCS7 failed" << std::endl; return -1;}
        BIO_flush(bio_encrypted_smime);

        //get internal data address
        const char* encrypted = NULL;
        BIO_get_mem_data(bio_encrypted_smime, &encrypted);  //encrypted has no new resource, only the reflection of the internal BIO data.
        //char encrypted[8 * 1024] = "";
        //copy BIO to char array
        //BIO_read(bio_encrypted_smime, encrypted, sizeof encrypted - 1); //if we read the data out of BIO, later we need to write it back, BIO_read deletes the internal data inside BIO
        std::cout << "PKCS7_encrypt length:" << strlen(encrypted) << std::endl << encrypted << std::endl;
        //please be careful while taking care of BIO object.
        //if we call BIO_read against BIO to get out data, the operation will cause the data deleted in the BIO at the same time.
        //here we recover BIO data.
        //BIO_write(bio_encrypted_smime, encrypted, strlen(encrypted));
        //BIO_flush(bio_encrypted_smime);

        BIO* bio_pkcs7 = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
        //read&load PKCS7 object from SMIME format.
        PKCS7* pkcs7_smime = SMIME_read_PKCS7(bio_encrypted_smime, &bio_pkcs7);
        if (NULL == pkcs7_smime) {std::cout << "SMIME_read_PKCS7 returns NULL" << std::endl;return -1;}
        BIO_flush(bio_pkcs7);
        BIO* bio_pkcs7_decrypt = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
        //decrypt in the way of PKCS7_decrypt
        if (0 == PKCS7_decrypt(pkcs7_smime, key, x509, bio_pkcs7_decrypt, 0)){ std::cout << "PKCS7_decrypt failed" << std::endl;return -1;}
        BIO_flush(bio_pkcs7_decrypt);
        //char decrypted[8 * 1024] = "";
        //dump decrypted data.
        //BIO_read(bio_pkcs7_decrypt, decrypted, sizeof decrypted - 1);
        const char* decrypted = NULL;
        //get internal data address
        BIO_get_mem_data(bio_pkcs7_decrypt, &decrypted);
        std::cout << "PKCS7_decrypt length: " << strlen(decrypted) << std::endl << decrypted << std::endl;

        //cleanup, idiot! donot forget to release resource you piece of shit!
        BIO_free(bio_pkcs7_decrypt);
        BIO_free(bio_pkcs7);
        BIO_free(bio_encrypted_smime);
        PKCS7_free(pkcs7_smime);
        PKCS7_free(pkcs7_encrypt);
    }
    X509_free(x509);
    sk_X509_pop_free(x509_stack, X509_free);

    return 0;
}
```

This piece of code works fine with openssl-1.0.1g. I tried both threads and no-threads config option.

But if we input one 224 length plain text WITHOUT the if-continue stuff, encryption is still working, it fails to decrypt in the method of SMIME_read_PKCS7, check backtrace comment above.

The length of encrypted S/MIME is 1200 in case of the length of input is 223.

In the case of 224 length input, the encrypted result which is in S/MIME format has length beyond 1200, SMIME_read_PKCS7 can not handle that length, check bt above for internal calls, but I have not find any document or page for explanation.

What is the secret of SMIME_read_PKCS7?

Defect 1:

With the help of @jww. There should be

```
BIO_set_mem_eof_return(bio_encrypted_smime, 0);
```

Before

```
PKCS7* pkcs7_smime = SMIME_read_PKCS7(bio_encrypted_smime, &bio_pkcs7);
```

Defect 2:

BIO_get_mem_data this one should return length of the data, actually we need to handle the char* based on the length, DO NOT just depend on the null termination unless you are expecting garbage value attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the secret of SMIME_read_PKCS7?

Well, no secret really. Its just buggy. According to the docs on [SMIME_read_PKCS7(3)](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/SMIME_read_PKCS7.html):

```
BUGS

The MIME parser used by SMIME_read_PKCS7() is somewhat primitive.
While it will handle most S/MIME messages more complex compound
formats may not work.

The parser assumes that the PKCS7 structure is always base64
encoded and will not handle the case where it is in binary
format or uses quoted printable format.

The use of a memory BIO to hold the signed content limits the
size of message which can be processed due to memory restraints:
a streaming single pass option should be available.
```

There's some good threads on the [OpenSSL User Group about `SMIME_read_PKCS7`](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mailing.openssl.users/SMIME_read_PKCS7).

Comment: Jesus Christ, how can I failed to check this. Thanks, one more confusion, the doc did not mention the limit value, how can I make sure this is the exact reason? What does that supposed to mean by saying: a streaming single pass option should be available? Is it a reasonable situation? It shouldn't be identified as defect if it is.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer, thanks again. The solution is BIO_set_mem_eof_return(bio_encrypted_smime, 0);